# Bad value mailto

Tags: php, html, mailto

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here. On W3c validator I get this error:

> Line 104, Column 43: Bad value
>   mailto:?subject=Test&body=I found this
>   today and i thought you might be
>   intrested.
>   URL/2011/05/test/
>   for attribute href on element a:
>   Control character in query component.
>   …     URL/2011/05/test/">http://example.org/. Characters should
>   be represented in NFC and spaces
>   should be escaped as %20

And this is the code I'm using in header.php:

```
<div style="float:left; width:25px; height:25px; padding:5px; margin-left:3px;">
    <a href="mailto:?subject=<?php the_title_attribute() ?>&amp;body=I found this today and i thought you might be intrested.
    <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><IMAGE SOURCE="<?php echo $template_url ?>/social/email-small.png" title="E-Mail"></a>
</div>
```

Its under`<!DOCTYPE html>` if that matters. Thanks in advance.

Sorry it made me break the links i just replaced with URL and IMAGE SOURCE

Comment: Not your problem, but "interested" is misspelled as "intrested" in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the parameters.

You can use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) in PHP.

Comment: @Wendy You can always give me the tick if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode any URLS you include in there.